# How to add new nodes in XML file in specific positions C#

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

I have an XML file:

```
    <resteraunts xmlns="http://w3.com">
  <resteraunt>
    <name>Little Italy Food</name>
  </resteraunt>
  <resteraunt>
    <name>Mark's Salads</name>
  </resteraunt>
  <resteraunt>
    <name>Greek Meals</name>
  </resteraunt>
</resteraunts>
```

I'm trying to add an Id to each restaurant under the  tag so it would look like this:

```
    <resteraunts xmlns="http://w3.com">
  <resteraunt>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <name>Little Italy Food</name>
  </resteraunt>
  <resteraunt>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <name>Mark's Salads</name>
  </resteraunt>
  <resteraunt>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <name>Greek Meals</name>
  </resteraunt>
</resteraunts>
```

I've tried using append, which only adds them to the bottom of the XML file. I've also tried this, but I receive an error that its null.

```
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        //Create a new node.
        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Id");
        elem.InnerText = myCounter.ToString();

        //Add the node to the document.
        root.InsertAfter(elem, root.FirstChild);
```

Comment: Any reason to add a namespace in your xml?

Comment: Yes, I need it to avoid conflicts. I changed it to something generic since it had the name of my school and city in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you need to be able to deal with namespaces.

```
const string ns = "http://w3.com";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
doc.Load("myXmlFile.xml");
nsManager.AddNamespace("n", ns);
var restaurants = doc.SelectNodes("/n:resteraunts/n:resteraunt", nsManager);
int myCounter = 1;
foreach (XmlNode restaurant in restaurants)
{
    var name = restaurant.SelectSingleNode("./n:name", nsManager);
    var id = doc.CreateElement("Id", ns);
    id.InnerText = myCounter.ToString();

    restaurant.InsertBefore(id, name);
    myCounter++;
}

doc.Save("myNewFile.xml");
```

This generates:

```xml
<resteraunts xmlns="http://w3.com">
  <resteraunt>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <name>Little Italy Food</name>
  </resteraunt>
  <resteraunt>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <name>Mark's Salads</name>
  </resteraunt>
  <resteraunt>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <name>Greek Meals</name>
  </resteraunt>
</resteraunts>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter?view=net-5.0#remarks), you should be able to insert the new node at the beginning of the list of child nodes by passing `refChild` as `null`.

```
//Add newNode as the first child of root.
root.InsertAfter(newNode, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ to XML

```
var document = XDocument.Load("path-to-file");

var restaurants = document.Descendants("resteraunt")
    .Select((e, i) => (Id: id, Element: e));
foreach (var e in restaurants)
{
    e.Element.Add("Id", e.Id);
}

document.Save("path-to-file");
```